# how to fix the cannot read property of 'image' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

im getting a 404 error on image get and im not sure what the cause is a some images work fine

```
                var $this=$(this),
                    movie = $this.data('movie');

                $('.active').removeClass('active');
                $this.addClass('active');

                $("#movieInfo").html(`

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
     **<img src='${movie.info.image}
                      'height="203" width="144"  class="img-thumbnail" /> '** <== this is the part the error is flagging
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-8">
       <h4>${movie.title}</h4>
       <ul class="list-group">
         <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Genre:</strong> ${movie.info.genres || 'N/A'}</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Year:</strong> ${movie.year}</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Released date:</strong> ${movie.info.release_date}</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Rank:</strong> ${movie.info.rank}</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Rating:</strong> ${movie.info.rating}</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Directors:</strong> ${movie.info.directors}</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Running Time:</strong> ${movie.info.running_time_secs}</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Actors:</strong> ${movie.info.actors}</li>

       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="well">
       <h5>Plot</h5>
       ${movie.info.plot}
       <hr>
       <a href="https://www.rottentomatoes.com/search/?search=${movie.title}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Rotten Tomatoes</a>
       <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-default">Go Back To Search</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   `);
```

[this is the inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuyvX.png)

I im struggling to find the issue as it is working for some but not others even though when i check the image addresses they are there.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a syntax error?

```
<img src='${movie.info.image}'height="203" width="144"  class="img-thumbnail" /> '
```

change to

```
<img src="${movie.info.image}" height="203" width="144"  class="img-thumbnail" />
```